# State updates might be asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

What exactly do they mean? If I understand [it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) correctly, I can't use `this.state` when calculating new state, unless I pass a function as a first parameter to `setState()`:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({a: f(this.state)});

// Correct
this.setState(prevState => {return {a: f(prevState)}});
```

But I can use `this.state` to decide what to do:

```
if (this.state.a)
    this.setState({b: 2});
```

What about props?

```
// Correct or wrong?
this.setState({name: f(this.props)});
```

And supposedly I can't expect `this.state` to change after calling `this.setState`:

```
this.setState({a: 1});
console.log(this.state.a);   // not necessarily 1
```

Then, say I have a list of users. And a select where I can make one user current:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    ...

    setCurrentUserOption(option) {
        this.setState({currentUserOption: option});
        if (option)
            ls('currentUserOption', option);
        else
            ls.remove('currentUserOption');
    }

    handleAddUser(user) {
        const nUsers = this.state.users.length;
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {users: prevState.users.concat(user)};
        }, () => {
            // here we might expect any number of users
            // but if first user was added, deleted and added again
            // two callbacks will be called and setCurrentUserOption
            // will eventually get passed a correct value

            // make first user added current
            if ( ! nUsers)
                this.setCurrentUserOption(this.userToOption(user));
        });
    }

    handleChangeUser(user) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {users: prevState.users.map(u => u.id == user.id ? user : u)};
        }, () => {
            // again, we might expect any state here
            // but a sequence of callback will do the right thing
            // in the end

            // update value if current user was changed
            if (_.get(this.state, 'currentUserOption.value') == user.id)
                this.setCurrentUserOption(this.userToOption(user));
        });
    }

    handleDeleteUser(id) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {users: _.reject(prevState.users, {id})};
        }, () => {
            // same here

            // choose first user if current one was deleted
            if (_.get(this.state, 'currentUserOption.value') == id)
                this.setCurrentUserOption(this.userToOption(this.state.users[0]));
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Do all callbacks are executed in sequence after batch of changes to state was applied?

On second thought, `setCurrentUserOption` is basically like `setState`. It enqueues changes to `this.state`. Even if callbacks get called in sequence, I can't rely on `this.state` being changed by previous callback, can I? So it might be best not to extract `setCurrentUserOption` method:

```
handleAddUser(user) {
    const nUsers = this.state.users.length;
    this.setState(prevState => {
        let state = {users: prevState.users.concat(user)};
        if ( ! nUsers) {
            state['currentUserOption'] = this.userToOption(user);
            this.saveCurrentUserOption(state['currentUserOption']);
        }
        return state;
    });
}

saveCurrentUserOption(option) {
    if (option)
        ls('currentUserOption', option);
    else
        ls.remove('currentUserOption');
}
```

That way I get queuing of changes to `currentUserOption` for free.

Comment: Just double checking are you using any state management frameworks like redux or flux? Answer could be different depending

Comment: I'm going to. But for now I want to make it work without `redux`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You didn't really ask a very specific question. "What does this mean" is not very much to go on. But you generally seem to understand the basics.

There are two possible ways to call `setState()`: either by passing it an object to get merged into the new state, or by passing it a function which returns an object which gets merged in a fashion similar to the first way.

So you either do this:

```
// Method #1
this.setState({foo: this.state.foo + 1}, this.someCallback);
```

Or this:

```
// Method #2
this.setState((prevState) => {return {foo: prevState.foo + 1}}, this.someCallback);
```

The main difference is that with method #1, `foo` will get incremented by 1 based on *whatever state it was at the time you call `setState()`*, while in method #2, `foo` will get incremented by 1 based on *whatever the previous state was in the instant that the arrow function runs*. So if you have multiple `setState()` calls that happen at the "same" time before the actual state update, with method #1 they may conflict and/or be based on outdated state, while with method #2 they are guaranteed to have the most up-to-date state because they update synchronously, one after another, in the state update phase.

Here is an illustrative example:

---

[Method #1 JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/xumuwovovu/1/edit?js,console,output)

```
// Method #1
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {n: 0};
    this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.increment();
    this.increment();
    this.increment();
  }
  increment() {
    this.setState({n: this.state.n + 1}, () => {console.log(this.state.n)});
  }
  render() {
    return (      
      <h1>{this.state.n}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

In the above: you would see this in the console:

```
> 1
> 1
> 1
```

And the final value of `this.state.n` would be `1`. All of the `setState()` calls were enqueued when the value of `n` was `0`, so they're all simply set it to `0 + 1`.

---

[Method #2 JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/xanapalepo/1/edit?js,console,output)

```
// Method #2
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {n: 0};
    this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.increment();
    this.increment();
    this.increment();
  }
  increment() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {return {n: prevState.n + 1}}, () => {console.log(this.state.n)});
  }
  render() {
    return (      
      <h1>{this.state.n}</h1>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

In the above, you would see this in the console:

```
> 3
> 3
> 3
```

And the final value of `n` would be `3`. Like with method #1, all of the `setState()` calls were enqueued at the same time. However, since they use a function to synchronously update in order using the most current state - including changes to state made by concurrent state updates - they properly increment `n` three times as you would expect.

---

Now, why does `console.log()` show `3` three times for method #2, instead of `1`, `2`, `3`? The answer is that `setState()` callbacks all happen together at the end of the state update phase in React, not immediately after that particular state update happens. So in that regard methods #1 and #2 are identical.

Comment: After the component has mounted and is in DOM, increment() is invoked 3 times with each invoking the setState. Since each setState modifies the state, why isn't the render invoked 3 times. I see that it is invoked only a single time eventually. Please advise.

Comment: @FarhanShirgillAnsari `setState()` calls are queued and processed in "batches" as part of the React internal cycle. There is not a "render" after every single change to state, instead they are all processed together as much as possible. Multiple state updates may only result in a single re-render if they were triggered at the same time synchronously.