# Why React say "State Updates May Be Asynchronous", "maybe" but not "must"?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am reading the docs of React, and I found that it says "State Updates May Be Asynchronous", but I am confused that why it's "maybe", not must? You can see the article from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

I know something about update batching or scheduler, are there updates not through batching, or not through scheduler's callback,I think async render maybe also running in microtask asynchronously.So why it's "maybe" but "must", is it relation to flushSync()?

Appreciate for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post
[State updates might be asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248204/state-updates-might-be-asynchronous)

But in addition to this post when you update a state sometimes if you do a fast enough call the state can be with the wrong value and due to that react suggest you call with a function that sends you back the prev state

Comment: I know this.setState((prevState) => newState) may solve the uncertainty of asynchronous update batch, thus it's still a asynchronous process for update.Why React just not say "State updates are certainly Asynchronous", like this, I am not sure whether there are some times  that updates are synchronous, maybe just on the current render without waiting?