# Set Array Value in setState in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to add data in set state (setArraytime) but array data value is not reflecting in setstate.

```
const [vehicle_type, setVehicleType] = useState("");
      const [endTime, setEndtime] = useState("");
      const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState("");
    
      const [array_time, SetArrayTime] = useState([]);

 let value = {
    interval: vehicle_type,
    startTime: startTime,
    endTime: endTime,
  };

const doArrayChunks = () => {
   

    var inputDataFormat = "HH:mm a";
    var outputFormat = "HH:mm a";
    var tmp = moment(vehicle_type, inputDataFormat);
    var dif = tmp - moment().startOf("day");

    var startIntervalTime = moment(startTime, inputDataFormat).add(-dif, "ms");
    var endIntervalTime = moment(startTime, inputDataFormat);
    var finishTime = moment(endTime, inputDataFormat);

   

    var intervals = [];
    while (startIntervalTime < finishTime) {
      var format =
        startIntervalTime.format(outputFormat) +
        " - " +
        endIntervalTime.format(outputFormat);
      intervals.push(format);
      startIntervalTime.add(dif, "ms");
      endIntervalTime.add(dif, "ms");
      console.log("Intervals", intervals);
      SetArrayTime(intervals);
      console.log("array_time", array_time);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code I can see that you want to replace the previous value of the array_time with the interval array. You can do it by using the below syntax

```
 SetArrayTime(prev_array_time => {
 let newArray = [...prev_array_time]
 newArray.push(intervals)
 return newArray
});
```

This should do the job.

[State updates might be asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248204/state-updates-might-be-asynchronous)

The above thread will help you understand whats happening in the background

Comment: no i dont want to replace the previous value because the array is empty and i want to add the result value (intervals[]) in setArraytime.

Comment: Have updated the code..This should help

Comment: its working but now if i render in html its not showing in page if you can help

Comment: Try using a useEffect hook with keeping the array_time as a watcher

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to expose the previous array within the update function like so:

```
SetArrayTime(existingArray => [...existingArray, ...intervals])
```

Comment: not updating i just wan to push the array (intervals[]) value to setArraytime

Comment: right then just call a function wrapped around the set state I propose above

Answer (score 0):

React changes the value of state when the callstack is empty.

As mentioned in the React documentation, there is no guarantee of setState being fired synchronously, so your console.log may return the state prior to it updating.

You can wait until the call stack is empty if you want to write out with

```
setTimeout(callback, 0)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack